# Why didn't addToBackStack fill the BackStack?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When I press the "Back" button (tested both on emulator and Galaxy S2) the applciation closes, no matter how many fragment transactions have been commited :(

Ok, just in case, I'll post my implementation of fragment transactions although I doubt they are the problem

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    Fragment fragment;
    switch(tab.getPosition()) {
    case(0):
        fragment = new Fragment1();
        break;
    case(1):
        fragment = new Fragment2();
        break;
    case(2):
        fragment = new Fragment3();
        break;
    default:
        fragment = new Fragment();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.okvir, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

And also

```
public void searchResultsView(List<School> results) {
    setResults(results);
    FragmentResults searchFragment = new FragmentResults();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    searchFragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.okvir, searchFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

And now I'll try to provide technical details about the application so you can figure out what's holding it back (irony).
The application has one Activity, and as you could conclude, utilizes ActionBar to initialize TabHost. The ActionBar.TabHost has three tabs attached to it which correspond to Fragment1, Fragment2, Fragment3. The FragmentResults is called from Fragment2 tab. If you require additional info, let me know in the comments.

Thank you for your time and effort. Cheers

P.S. Interenstingly, when I call DialogFragment, even without AddToBackStack(null) method pressing "Back" button returns to the fragment that called it and doesn't close the app...

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE THIS:

```
ft.replace(R.id.okvir, fragment);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

TO THIS:

```
ft.replace(R.id.okvir, fragment,"TAGNAME");
ft.addToBackStack("TAGNAME");
ft.commit();
```

I WAS OMRI FROM ISRAEL HOPE ITS HELP IF U HAVE MORE PROBLAM CONTECT ME 
omlrc1991@gmail.com